# Bootstrap grid: fluid to "one side"

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on a lay-out using Bootstrap's grid system.
I currently have something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-8">...</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">...</div>
</div>
```

What I actually want to achieve is for the second column to take up the rest of the horizontal space available, i.e. the second column behaves as if it is in a fluid container but the first column still behaves as if in a fixed container.

I tried using the :after pseudo-selector to introduce a block that appears next to the second column (this would be okay since the "whole-width-column"-thing is purely for cosmetic reasons), but I couldn't get it to take up *all* space.

If anyone has any ideas on how to achieve this in a nice way, that would be very much appreciated.

**Edit:** to make things a bit more visual: [image: An example of what I want to achieve]

The red block is what I currently have (a column of width 4), the green block is what I'd like to be there.

Comment: I don't see your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/680/

Comment: The problem is that on larger screens, the right side of the right column doesn't stretch to the right edge of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/titik/1/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-8">Content</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"><div class="well">Words go in here words go in here Words go in here words go in here Words go in here words go in here Words go in here words go in here Words go in here words go in here </div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {overflow-x:hidden}

.well {
    z-index: 3;
    border: 0px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
.well:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:80%;
    right:-3000px;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Well, just making a very wide :after-element does indeed work, but I find it an ugly solution. It causes the page to become very wide, and I know that's solvable with an overflow:hidden, but... meh.

Comment: And you'll see, that if you intend to use Bootstrap's container and have a margin-left:auto, margin-right: auto, then this is the deal.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid it's the only feasible way to achieve what I want, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

Alternative solution if you're using bootstrap's SASS:

```
// Custom mixin to generate container-fluid-left and container-fluid-right (fluid on the left/right and normal max width on the other)
// For each breakpoint, define the maximum width of the container in a media query
@mixin make-container-fluid-side-max-widths($side, $max-widths: $container-max-widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  margin-#{$side}: 0;
  padding-#{$side}: 0; 

  .row{
    margin-#{$side}: 0;
  }

  .col, .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-auto{
    padding-#{$side}: 0;
  }

  @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
      max-width: calc( 100% - (100% - #{$container-max-width}) / 2 );
    }
  }
}


.container-fluid-left {
  @include make-container();
  @include make-container-fluid-side-max-widths('left');
}

.container-fluid-right {
  @include make-container();
  @include make-container-fluid-side-max-widths('right');
}
```

Generates two classes - `container-fluid-left` and `container-fluid-right` - which will be fluid on the left/right side and only ocupy on the same space as a normal container on the other.

Comment: Based on same needs as OP, this is the answer that worked for me with Bootstrap 5.2x. This is the cleanest answer IMO.

Answer (score 8):

I have found an elegant solution to this.
The wrapping container class is used to change the behavior of the containers under it rather than changing it globally.

Also, margin-right: 0 is used to set the container fluid from the right, you can use margin-left: 0 to set it fluid to the other side.

N.B: If the container didn't reach the edge of the screen, just remove the padding from the column.

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
  .YourWrappingContainerClass .container {
    width: calc(((100% - 750px) / 2) + 750px) !important;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .YourWrappingContainerClass .container {
    width: calc(((100% - 970px) / 2) + 970px) !important;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
  .YourWrappingContainerClass .container {
    width: calc(((100% - 1170px) / 2) + 1170px) !important;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

[bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) [container](/questions/tagged/container) [container-fluid](/questions/tagged/container-fluid) [css](/questions/tagged/css)

Comment: It's beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: This seems to shift the whole container to the right rather than keeping the left column aligned with the rest of the page (using Bootstrap 5)

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is set the right padding of the container to 0 and override the max-width that bootstrap puts on it.

```
.container {
    padding-right: 0px;
    max-width: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/682/)

EDIT: One more solution you can try is this:

```
.container {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    max-width: none;
}
```

[New Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/685/)

Comment: That seems to work with Bootstrap 3.0.0, but no longer with 3.2.0.

Comment: @Mathijs Weird that they made a change like that from 3.0 to 3.2. Updated my answer.

Comment: The width: initial causes the container to become full-width, so it effectively turns it into a container-fluid. This then causes the left column to stretch to the left side of the page which is not desirable.

Comment: I updated my answer again. It's hard to tell if these will work for you or not; I can only assume it will work if it works in the fiddle.

Comment: It does not work in the fiddle: if you make your browser screen really wide, you'll see that again the whole container just sticks to the right of the page.

Comment: Apparently my monitor is not wide enough, because from what I can tell it looks like you are wanting. Initial left margin is the same with the right column extending all the way over. Sorry for not being more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This code work screen size limit 1200px to greater. check this code only in device greater than 1200px. if device size smaller then 1200px layout is normal [Demo](https://codepen.io/GooglePagal/pen/QWyveKE)

```css
.main-box {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  height: 50px;
}

.first-col {
  background-color: #f4b334;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .first-col {
    padding-left: calc((100% - 1160px) / 2);
    /* 1160px is your container width or web width*/
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container-fluid main-box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 first-col">
      <h2>Hello World</h2>
      <p>this is example text</p>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 .container {
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
```

This applies a margin of 0 to all sides except the left, which is set to auto. Then to get the second column to butt against the right hand side remove the padding.

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/MnGu6mBCI2)

Comment: This moves the whole container to the right of the page, whereas I want the left edge of the container to remain at the same position, while the right edge stretches to the right edge of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same thing as well. I made a version right now that works for 1/3 column on the left and 2/3 + full width column on the right. If time left, I can add all the options based on all col-*-* options.

What I did is use the 100vw and deduct (with SASS variables ) the fixed width and half of this to add to the left margin, and on the right hand side 0 marging. The columns i split up into 1/3 and 2/3 + the margin again:

```
.container-fluid-right {
    width:calc(100vw - 30px) !important;
    overflow-x:visible;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;

    > .row > :first-child {
        padding-left:15px;
        padding-right:15px;
    }
    > .row > :last-child {
        padding-right:0px;
        padding-left:0px;
        float:right;
        margin-right: 0px;

    }


    @include when-sm { 
        > .row > :first-child {
            width:calc(#{$screen-sm-min} * 1 / 3);
            margin-left: calc((100vw - #{$screen-sm-min}) / 2);
        }
        > .row > :last-child {
            width:calc((#{$screen-sm-min} * 2 / 3) +((100vw - #{$screen-sm-min}) / 2));
        }
    }
    @include when-md { 
        > .row > :first-child {
            width:calc(#{$screen-md-min} * 1 / 3);
            margin-left: calc((100vw - #{$screen-md-min}) / 2);
        }
        > .row > :last-child {
            width:calc((#{$screen-md-min} * 2 / 3) +((100vw - #{$screen-md-min}) / 2));
        }
    }
    @include when-lg { 
        > .row > :first-child {
            width:calc(#{$screen-lg-min} * 1 / 3);
            margin-left: calc((100vw - #{$screen-lg-min}) / 2);
        }
        > .row > :last-child {
            width:calc((#{$screen-lg-min} * 2 / 3) +((100vw - #{$screen-lg-min}) / 2));
        }
    }
}
```

I used when-sm / when-md / when-lg from another poster, these are the mixins:

```
@mixin when-xs() { @media (max-width: $screen-xs-max) { @content; } }
@mixin when-sm() { @media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) { @content; } }
@mixin when-md() { @media (min-width: $screen-md-min) { @content; } }
@mixin when-lg() { @media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) { @content; } }
```

For the original posters layout (8 left 4 right) the only difference would be switching the 1/3 and 2/3 around

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and decided to just skip the .container class altogether. I created a class called .container-only-left like this

```
.container-only-left {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 255px);

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        margin-left: calc(50% - 345px);
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        margin-left: calc(50% - 465px);
    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        margin-left: calc(50% - 555px);
    }
}
```

As long as the .container-only-left class is put inside an element that covers 100vw this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Version for Bootstrap 5 if you're using the pre-compiled CSS.  Hat tip to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64542602/1096128

```
.container-fluid-right {
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;

    .row{
        margin-right: 0;
        
        > [class*=' col-']:last-child,
        > [class^='col-']:last-child{
            padding-right: 0;
        }
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .container-fluid-right {
        max-width: calc( 100% - (100% - 540px) / 2 );
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-fluid-right {
        max-width: calc( 100% - (100% - 720px) / 2 );
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container-fluid-right {
        max-width: calc( 100% - (100% - 960px) / 2 );
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container-fluid-right {
        max-width: calc( 100% - (100% - 1200px) / 2 );
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
    .container-fluid-right {
        max-width: calc( 100% - (100% - 1320px) / 2 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/sawacrow/pen/Jjmvydx

```
      <div class="container-fluid-sticky-right bg-success"><h1>sticky right container</h1></div>

  <div class="container "><h1>normal container</h1></div>

  <div class="container-fluid-sticky-left bg-warning"><h1>sticky left container</h1></div>
```

js

```
    function containerFluidder() {
  var container = document.querySelector('.container');
  var distanceFromWindow = container.offsetLeft;
  var containerStyles = window.getComputedStyle(container);
  var paddingOneSide = parseInt(containerStyles.paddingLeft)
  distanceFromWindow = distanceFromWindow + paddingOneSide;
    document.querySelectorAll('.container-fluid-sticky-left').forEach((el) => {
    el.style.marginRight = distanceFromWindow + 'px';
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.container-fluid-sticky-right').forEach((el) => {
    el.style.marginLeft = distanceFromWindow + 'px';
    });
}
containerFluidder();
//add event listener to window resize and call containerFluidder
window.addEventListener('resize', containerFluidder);
```